# The code for the first task switches in a RTOS

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, embedded

I was reading recently about real time operating systems in micro controllers (especially AVR), and I am trying to write a simple one for (AVR). My question is about the context switch ...

So, taskA executes and gets interrupted by the ISR which decides that another task (i.e taskB) should run now, then the context (register file, stack pointer, status register) of taskB is loaded, and upon exiting the ISR, because the "stack pointer" was set in the right place (just above the program counter of taskB, which was saved on the stack when taskB was interrupted by ISR) the code will execute for taskB. This is what I've understood so far reading the internet.

My question is: how everything starts? If this is for first time taskA gets interrupted, then what is loaded for taskB? There is no program counter for taskB on stack and no stack pointer to be loaded therefore. How to code this?

Comment: It's started by the bootloader as any other OS.

Comment: Maybe is not clear from the question, but I am trying to write my own RTOS ... and I do not understand how to code that part :)

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: You need to read the specifications for your controller. Each controller has an address from which it starts running code. Sometimes it's 0x000000, sometimes it's another address.
That address is usually mapped to a storage component on the chip, so you need to compile your image to have the 1st instruction in that address.
From there - it's all a matter of design and implementation...

Comment: _"Why the down vote?"_ Because your question is too broad. You'll need to write a small bootloader that initializes the ISRs and jumps to a main entry point of your program.

Comment: Usually I am uploading the code on the chip using ISP programming, not a bootloader ... Can I do the same if the program is actually using a RTOS? Is a bootloader mandatory in this case?

Comment: @immortal As I understood that would be the program counter ... but the program counter is never used in a RTOS, it is assumed to be loaded on the stack once the task was interrupted, and the context switch just makes sure to move the stack pointer in the right spot. But I do not know how to add new tasks ...

Comment: Essentially you just allocate a new area in memory that bill become the stack of your new thread/task and also create the task control block somewhere.  Everything else are platform specific details, for which you have to read the documentation of your processor and maybe your compiler.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you find yourself in need of a RTOS while using a AVR, you picked the wrong MCU to begin with.

Comment: @Lundin At this moment, I am just trying to learn how to write a simple context switching and scheduler ...

Comment: @user0042 : That is not what he is asking; he is asking about task/thread starting, not OS starting.  Nothing to do with any bootloader. And that is not how a bootloader starts `main()` in any case.  A microcontroller such as an AVR is unlikley to have a bootloader other then the simple one already in mask ROM.  You should perhaps refrain from downvoting questions you simply don't understand.  The question is not too broad my any measure.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, it goes something like this:

Thread A calls the OS 'CreateThread()' API, (lets assume valid arguments:).

The new thread B will need a stack, so the memory-management is called to provide enough virtual memory for the stack size passed in the call, (or some default).

This stack top is then loaded with all the thread-private stuff that the OS design deems to be required for any thread to access with thread API's.

The code start address, flag resister or whatever of the thread code is loaded into the B stack so as to make the bottom of the B stack look like the thread B has been in existence before and interrupted into the kernel.

The new thread B can then be started for the first time just as if it is not the first time, eg. by loading the stack pointer and an interrupt-return.

[note - assumes stack grows downwards, like x86]

Answer (score 2):

On task creation an initial context is built (in the *task control block* -
 TCB - for the task), with the program counter set to the address of the task entry-point, and the stack pointer set to the start address of the tasks stack.  These initial values are the ones loaded when the task is first scheduled.

So in summary, the initial task context is *synthesised* rather than *saved* from previous execution.

Typically the initial context is built in a `createTask` function, and the for the context for the initial task is loaded by a `startSheduler` function.

Comment: Sir, thank you for your attention ... this is actually what I've done after all. When I am creating a new task am am allocating 64 (it should be enough) bytes of memory for the new task stack (using malloc() ... :D ), then I am setting the stack pointer to point to that  memory location returned by malloc (it should be that or that + 64?? ), then I am pushing on the "new stack" the function pointer of the handler, then saving in the TCB structure the already modified (because of PUSH) stack pointer ... is it OK?

Comment: Probably I should change back the stack pointer with the value it has when first entered "createNewTask(...)" ?!

Comment: @CMarius : SO is not a discussion forum.  You asked a generic question about RTOS.  If you have further questions about _ your_ specific implementation, post a new question. Comments are not for ongoing lengthy discussion.

Answer (score 1):

After you have your tasks/threads set up in main(), you'll need to call an OS.start() or similar.  By necessity, that run the task scheduler to find the highest priority task which is ready to run.

This scheduler will need to discern between a task which has never run, (thus has not thread context to pop off the stack), and one which has been preempted.

```
void scheduler(void)
{
   //find the next ready task
   ...code...

   if(theReadyTask.hasPreviouslyRun)
   {
       //the task was preempted and needs its context restored
       ...code to load load the registers off of the stack...
   }
   //whether it has run before or not we need to change the stack pointer so the return jumps to the function associated with the thread.
   ...code to set stack pointer...
}
```

So once a task has started the first time, it will always have a context to be returned to.  But the first time in it needs special handling...

Comment: No problem.  Feel free to upvote or accept if it was useful to you.

Comment: In the case of AVR uC the memory for every task is obtained using malloc? And then at the task creation, the stack pointer is loaded with the pointer returned by malloc function?

Comment: On an embedded system, dynamic memory allocation is not recommended, for reasons which are documented fairly extensively around the site.  Also, the AVR has a Harvard architecture, which means the program space and data space are different memory all together.  So you have a call stack and a data stack as two separate things.  So you're restoring both a call stack (to return to the right place) and the data stack (to ensure the registers are configured as they were when the task was preempted.)

Comment: You're likely to have more success in investigating an existing RTOS to get all the concepts before experimenting rolling your own.  Try http://www.freertos.org/a00098.html

Comment: I am doing this sort of in parallel and several other sources

Comment: @CMarius :  On small systems where threads are not dynamically created and destroyed, the stack for each task would typically be statically allocated.

Answer (score 0):

In embedded systems, like AVR, you often need to create tasks at the beginning of program. These tasks can create or terminate new tasks.

```
int main() {
    Task *A = createTask(.....);
    while(1) {
        processTasks();
    }
}
```

Here `createTask(.....);` function insert the task A to the task queue of pending tasks and `processTasks();` function takes a tasks (i.e. A) from task queue and executes them. The `.....` means a lot of arguments necessary for RTOS like function handler, TCB, priority,...

Furthermore then `main()` is actually also a task.

Of course there are a lot of stuff around and it is not simple problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question; it is merely a pseudo-code of a typical RTOS task creation and scheduling initiation.  What he appears to be asking is how a task without an existing context starts first time.  "by calling functionX" does not really answer that.